# Edit a .js file to make the program invisible

Tags: javascript

I have been using K9 Web Protection for a while now and it's great from many aspects, expect that it's possibly too conspicuous. So I want to install it but without making everyone around notice a blocking software on the machine.

So what I did is use Resource Hacker to edit the .js file by adding the mention :

`'window.location=about:blank'`.

This way, whenever a page is blocked by the software, I am just redirected to a blank page. This works great except for the fact that the title of the window still displays "K9 Web Protection Alert" for a few seconds before fading away. This is pretty much unnoticeable with IE or Safari but is very obvious with Firefox and Chrome.

So I'm looking for a way to implement this feature as well or any other feature that would make the program more discrete, possibly by editing the .js file. Any help for that ?

For completeness, you can access the .js file at this address : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bys21N2WukhpOGIzOTBmZDUtYjlmNC00MjMxLTkwMmUtZGFkNjZkMWIzNzY0

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the line `document.title = "";` before the line you've added yourself?